# Who lived on Golden Square in London in the 18th century?

Tags: england, united-kingdom, 18th-century, records, london

Is there a database or an archive where I could find a list of the inhabitants of Golden Square in London in the 18th century?

I know that a famous musician of that time was living on that square, and I'm trying to find in which house exactly and at what time he was there. I know he was in London from 1729 and died in 1750.

Comment: Which famous musician do you have in mind?

Comment: Giuseppe St Martini, he was italian oboe player and composer, compared to Corelli and Handel by the most important music historian of that time, supposed to be the best oboe player of his time. He was working for the Prince of Wales from 1736 to 1751. He doesn't seem to be named in the British history online website about the Golden Square but I know from some official document that he was living at the Golden Square in a 3 floor's house when he died.

Comment: @rachkouti I found a reference in the 1900 edition of [British music publishers, printers and engravers](https://archive.org/stream/cu31924021638402#page/n99/mode/2up) that claims compositions by Giuseppe St Martini were actually written by James Oswald. Is it possible that Giuseppe St Martini was a _nom de plume_ used by Oswald?

Comment: @sempaiscuba, no. Giuseppe St Martini is born in Milan (his birth certificate is known), played numerous concerts between 1710 and 1750, first in Italy, then in Belgium, then in England. Attribution of music piece can be a puzzle, but they are many pieces between 1715 and 1750 which have been composed by Giuseppe St Martini (no need of a nom de plume). Thanks for this link.

Answer (score 7):

The [British History Online](http://www.british-history.ac.uk/) website has several pages taken from the Survey of London about Golden Square which may have the information you're looking for.

1. There is an [overview](http://www.british-history.ac.uk/survey-london/vols31-2/pt2/pp138-145) of the history and development of the square. This includes a plan of the square and does list some famous residents.
2. A history and list of occupiers of the properties on the [west side](http://www.british-history.ac.uk/survey-london/vols31-2/pt2/pp146-154) of the square (house numbers 1 to 12)
3. A history and list of occupiers of the properties on the [north side](http://www.british-history.ac.uk/survey-london/vols31-2/pt2/pp154-156) of the square (house numbers 13 to 19)
4. A history and list of occupiers of the properties on the [east side](http://www.british-history.ac.uk/survey-london/vols31-2/pt2/pp156-162) of the square (house numbers 19A to 31)
5. A history and list of occupiers of the properties on the [south
   side](http://www.british-history.ac.uk/survey-london/vols31-2/pt2/pp162-165) of the square (house numbers 32 to 38)

Comment: Many thanks for this very useful link which I didn't know. Unfortunately Mr. St Martini is not listed among the known occupants. At least now I know that he was not living in n.3-6-8-9-22-23-24-25-26-33-37 and 38 (in 1750 when he dies in his house, the inhabitants of those houses are known).